# Which is the shortest way to list a running process?

Tags: command-line, process, ps

I often need to check if a process is running, so I use one of these:

```
ps aux | grep myprocess
ps -Fe | grep myprocess
top
pgrep myprocess (only shows the PID)
pkill myprocess (if I want to kill it)
```

All of the above commands work well but, is there a shorter command to do this?
Any answer is appreciated, but the chosen one needs to be...

- A built in solution, as I work with many different devices.
- Enables to use a pattern.
- Gives you similar information than ps aux.
- Shorter than what we already know.

Thanks

Comment: is above commands are hard to understand? Why you need a shorter one?

Comment: No, I understand them. Because I use them over 20 times a day.

Comment: How much shorter than `pgrep myprocess` do you need to get? What Doesn't that do that you need?

Comment: It only gives me the PID by default. Is not much information. A command of that length with the info that ps aux gives you would be ideal :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're asking for doesn't exist so why not write a little bash function or script that does exactly what you want?

```
function p {
    ps aux | awk -v s="$@" 'NR>1 && $11~s'
}
```

Stick that in your `~/.bash_functions` (or wherever is called by `~/.bashrc`) and call `source ~/.bashrc` to reload it and you should be able to run:

```
$ p firefox
oli       5992 11.2  4.2 2856240 1044104 ?     Sl   Jun17 313:56 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

The expression will take a regex which makes it doubly handy. And `p` on its own will give you a full listing.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Not with the `$@` argument IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

Using alias & grep to filter out its own terminal process :

```
alias qp="ps aux | grep -E -v \"tty.*grep|pts.*grep\" | grep -m1"
```

If you want last/newest process:

```
alias qp="ps ax | tac | grep -E -v \"tty.*grep|pts.*grep\" | grep -m1"
```

Answer (score 0):

It give the process id if running and not if not running

> pidof process

Comment: Thanks but I would like to be able to use a pattern and also get more info than the pid

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are very good and basically wrap up your ad hoc solution of `ps | grep` into a shell alias or function. There is nothing wrong with that approach. Note, however, that this means `ps` will be extracting information for all running processes and then you have `awk` or `grep` filtering out the lines of interest.

I would propose that it's slightly more efficient to use `pgrep` to get a list of PIDs (as you show in your question), and use `ps` to get the output format you want for only the PIDs matched by `pgrep`.

#### Simple process match, POSIX-style *full* listing

```bsh
pg() {
    pids=`pgrep -d, "$1"`
    [ "$pids" ] && ps -f -p "$pids"
}

pg myprocess
```

This shows a full `ps` listing for the matched process names. This function definition can be added to `~/.bashrc` to always be defined in your interactive shell. This can also be modified in a few different ways to change the output format or to match full command lines instead of just the process name.

#### Simple process match, BSD-style *user* listing

```bsh
pg() {
    pids=`pgrep -d, "$1"`
    [ "$pids" ] && ps up "$pids"
}
```

#### Full command-line match, BSD-style *job control* listing

```bsh
pg() {
    pids=`pgrep -f -d, "$1"`
    [ "$pids" ] && ps jp "$pids"
}
```

#### Full command-line match, POSIX-style *long* listing

```bsh
pg() {
    pids=`pgrep -f -d, "$1"`
    [ "$pids" ] && ps -l -p "$pids"
}
```

Note the `-f` option on `pgrep` in the last two examples to match on the full command line. You can alter these examples to suit your needs, the important part being that the `p` or `-p` option is given with the list of PIDs found by `pgrep`.